# How do I log into a Gitlab CI container?

Tags: php, docker, gitlab, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I need to install via composer a private package from the corporate namespace in Gitlab CI.

Dependency in composer.json.

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@gitlab.com:namespace/package.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "namespace/package": "dev-master",
     }
```

In .gitlab.ci.yml

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/namespace/project:1.0.0

stages:
    - deploy

.setup_ssh: &setup_ssh
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client zip unzip -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan $DEV_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

.setup_composer: &setup_composer
    - composer i -n

deploy to dev:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - *setup_ssh
        - *setup_composer
```

Installing composer i -n crashes on a private package.

> Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-namespace-package.git'...                                                  
>   remote:                                                                                                                                           
>   remote: ========================================================================                                                                  
>   remote:                                                                                                                                           
>   remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.                                              
>   remote:                                                                                                                                           
>   remote: ========================================================================                                                                  
>   remote:                                                                                                                                           
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                     
>                                                                                                                                                     
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                               
>   and the repository exists.

I tried running the container locally and installing the composer dependencies inside the container interactively.

> - Syncing namespace/package (dev-master fa27046) into cache
> Cloning failed, enter your GitLab credentials to access private repos
> A token will be created and stored in "/root/.composer/auth.json", your password will never be stored
> To revoke access to this token you can visit https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

I have 2FA configured. For the test, I created a token and tried to log in.

```
composer config --global gitlab-token.gitlab.com [token]
```

After that, everything worked. But the problem is that this is my personal token.

How do I log into a Gitlab CI container?

Comment: Are you asking how to authenticate to a private package repository within your CI context? If so, you should check out using the CI_JOB_TOKEN variable within CI/CD.

Comment: I check it. I get auth error.

[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                            
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://private-token:h9s...zuK@gitlab.com/namespace/package.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-namespace-package.git'

Comment: Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-namespace-package.git'...                                                                              
  remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied                                                                                                                                             
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/namespace/package.git/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and it's very simple!

To deploy the main project to the server, I added the public key Deploy keys in the settings.

So, it was necessary to enable this key in the settings of EACH private repository, which is in the composer.json dependencies.

**Private package Repo > Settings > Repository > Deploy Keys > Privately accessible deploy keys > Enable** (key from main project)

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtvFh.png)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/#how-to-enable-deploy-keys

Comment: This... shouldn't be necessary. What are you doing with the deploy key? Anything you do with the deploy key you should be able to do with the CI job token, which would be much more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an auth.json with your Gitlab Token next to your composer.json. This is automatically used by Composer if existent. With that you can auth in automated processes like CI deployment.
Maybe create a project specific Gitlab user that has access to everything the project needs - and nothing else. Then use the token of that user.

See for more details on auth.json: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md